# Images not showing in my development environment with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am getting in my logs:

```
Processing by ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"signed_blob_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBbllYIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--882d67a6af266354eb355e33060e83b14392b7dd", "variation_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9VWTI5dFltbHVaVjl2Y0hScGIyNXpld2c2QzNKbGMybDZaVWtpRFRZd01IZzBNREJlQmpvR1JWUTZDMlY0ZEdWdWRFa2lERFl3TUhnME1EQUdPd2RVT2d4bmNtRjJhWFI1U1NJTFkyVnVkR1Z5QmpzSFZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--3d3c1b8fcf97978bbeefe89263187c2b76921aff", "filename"=>"product_image"}
Filter chain halted as :set_blob rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have the correct keys in my `storage.yml` file, and I am using the same database as in my production build (where the images are working fine). In the front the urls are showing like:

```
src="/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBbllYIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--882d67a6af266354eb355e33060e83b14392b7dd/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9VWTI5dFltbHVaVjl2Y0hScGIyNXpld2c2QzNKbGMybDZaVWtpRFRZd01IZzBNREJlQmpvR1JWUTZDMlY0ZEdWdWRFa2lERFl3TUhnME1EQUdPd2RVT2d4bmNtRjJhWFI1U1NJTFkyVnVkR1Z5QmpzSFZBPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6InZhcmlhdGlvbiJ9fQ==--3d3c1b8fcf97978bbeefe89263187c2b76921aff/product_image"
```

I am using rails 5.2.4.4

I can see this is the line giving problems:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/controllers/concerns/active_storage/set_blob.rb#L12

I have tried it in my local console and it gives back:

```
      @blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(params[:signed_blob_id] || params[:signed_id])
```

```
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)
```

Images generated with:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(image.variant(resize: "600x400^", extent: "600x400"), only_path: true)
```